How do I utilize the UMAP coordinates to replicate the UMAP visualization described in a paper?
I aim to recreate a UMAP plot using the UMAP coordinates extracted from their metadata file. The article and the GEO accession are these: Molgora M, et al. TREM2 Modulation Remodels the Tumor Myeloid Landscape Enhancing Anti-PD-1 Immunotherapy. Cell. 2020. GEO accession: GSE151710
The datasets I want to use are only: GSM4588939 and GSM4588940. I want to assemble the same UMAP as in supplementary figure S2, using the UMAP coordinates from the metadata file GSE151710_meta_single_cell_2_total_CD45.tsv.gz. How should I do?
I would like to know what code for R I can use. Thanks!

The following worked for me. Depending on downstream applications you may want to integrate the data rather than merge the two samples.
Pull down the data
Using linux terminal here, but can be done through https download from NCBI.
#count matrices
wget https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE151nnn/GSE151710/suppl/GSE151710_RAW.tar
tar -xf GSE151710_RAW.tar 

#coordinates
wget https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE151nnn/GSE151710/suppl/GSE151710_meta_single_cell_2_total_CD45.tsv.gz
gunzip GSE151710_meta_single_cell_2_total_CD45.tsv.gz

Load libraries
library(Seurat)
library(tidyverse)

Load count matricies into R
spar.matrix <- Read10X_h5("GSM4588939_TREM2_WT_1_filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5",
use.names = TRUE, unique.features = TRUE)

seu.obj_GSM4588939 <- CreateSeuratObject(spar.matrix, project = "trem_ms_data")

spar.matrix <- Read10X_h5("GSM4588940_TREM2_WT_2_filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5",
use.names = TRUE, unique.features = TRUE)
seu.obj_GSM4588940 <- CreateSeuratObject(spar.matrix, project = "trem_ms_data")

seu.obj <- merge(seu.obj_GSM4588939, seu.obj_GSM4588940)

Load in coordinates from NCBI
The cell names in the tsv file do not match the H5 object, so the code
cleans up the barcodes so they match.
cellID.df <- read.table("./GSE151710_meta_single_cell_2_total_CD45.tsv")
cellID.df <- cellID.df %>% 
  filter(Sample %in% c("WT_1", "WT_2")) %>% 
  rownames_to_column()

cellID.df$rowname <- paste0(substr(cellID.df$rowname, 6, nchar(cellID.df$rowname)), "-1")
cellID.df <- cellID.df %>%
  mutate(
    rowname = ifelse(grepl("1", Sample), 
      paste0(rowname, "_1"),
      paste0(rowname, "_2")
    )
  )

Store the coordinates in the Seurat object and plot
umap.coords <- cellID.df %>%
  select(rowname, UMAP_1, UMAP_2) %>%
  column_to_rownames()

seu.obj <- subset(seu.obj, cells = rownames(umap.coords))

seu.obj@reductions$umap <- CreateDimReducObject(
    embeddings = as.matrix(umap.coords), assay = "RNA", key = "UMAP_")

p <- DimPlot(seu.obj, reduction = "umap") + NoLegend()
ggsave("umap.png")

Add in additional metadata
clusters <- cellID.df$Cluster
names(clusters) <- cellID.df$rowname
seu.obj <- AddMetaData(seu.obj, metadata = clusters, col.name = "orig.clusters")

p <- DimPlot(seu.obj, reduction = "umap", group.by = "orig.clusters")
ggsave("umap_clusters.png")

Versions of key packages:
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
tidyverse_1.3.1
SeuratObject_4.1.3
Seurat_4.3.0
ggplot2_3.3.6

UMAP of the data with the coordinates from the original publication

Thanks. I would also like to know, using this same dataset, how to cluster my UMAP plot using the Cluster column in the file: "./GSE151710_meta_single_cell_2_total_CD45.tsv"?

See code added under the "Add in additional metadata" section. Note that I modified the earlier code to store the umap coordinates as umap.coords, so may want to re-run all the code.
